# Chat room practically abandoned, make an effort to revive it?

Tags: discussion

I don't spend much time in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/327/drupal-answers), and scrolling back the history, I get the impression that neither does anyone else.

I think it's a bit unfortunate, because it could probably be a good resource, for example, for discussing closing of question and other moderation like tasks.

Of course, if no one is in the room, then there's little incentive for anyone else to join as well.

I suggest some people make an effort to stick around for a while, to help the chat get some momentum. We could even **say** something ;)

I'll be around for a while, let me know what you think. :)

Comment: I think this discussion would be more suited to a chat room :P I don't know about anyone else but I just don't have the time for chatting these days. I mean, we have our super-secret mod chat room where we talk about you all and plot various doomsday scenarios, of course, but we can get through those plots pretty efficiently these days. Kudos for the suggestion though, the cobwebs in DA's chat are definitely building up

Comment: Hey, could you, umm, post a link to room directly? I'm too lazy to look for it, ya know :P

Comment: Ha :) There is a link in the top menu to the general chat, right next to the main/meta menu link. With that said, that leads to "all" chats. I've added a link in the question to the DA-specific one I had in mind. :)

Comment: I already spend time here and on IRC at the same time as finding my feet in a new job, I don't think I can afford another distraction throughout the day :-p

Comment: IRC is where it is. End of story :P

Answer (score 3):

I think SE is missing a protocol for alerting interested parties about "chats".

For instance some of the questions closed as "too broad" may benefit from open ended and looser discussions in chat.  However, there is currently no real mechanism for doing that.

An idea is to offer OPs that see their questions closed an option to set up a chat room for the closed question. And if he/she does an invitation to join the chat room will be added to the closed poster as long as the chat room is exists,

Answer (score 0):

Now after trying it, I don't think it's a good idea.

There were only 4 people and 2 separate discussions going on. Noise. Not comfortable to use. I'm not surprised that in it's current form it went into oblivion, and I don't think resurrecting it without serious approach change was a good idea.

Chat for general chatter - all right. Using "main" chat for serious problems? Does not work for me. One chat per serious topic + main chat for people not engaged in any serious business at the moment, now that might work.