# Chat room truly abandoned, can it be unfronzen?

Tags: support

So I guess we can consider 
[Chat room practically abandoned, make an effort to revive it?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/chat-room-practically-abandoned-make-an-effort-to-revive-it) a failure ;)

Now the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/327/drupal-answers) has been "automatically frozen for inactivity".

Can the room be unfrozen, or is the right thing to do, to create a new room?

Creating a new room seems like it would have *even less* likelihood of being used, so I'm hoping we can unfreeze the existing one. :)

Comment: Maybe we should try to create some weekly meetings? What day / time would be OK?

Comment: @Mołot I like the idea, Once we've worked the "which room to be in" question, maybe we should open a new meta question with suggestions?

Comment: Well, on the other hand, does "which" matters if we will not figure out "why"?

Comment: @Mołot True. You wanna open a new question about it?

Comment: Here: http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/q/3112/16495

Comment: I unfreezed the room, but that won't prevent it from being frozen again if it stays inactive.

Comment: @MadScientist Of course. Thank you. :)