# What to do with chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

Chatroom [was frozen](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3111/16495). Attempts to [revive](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2705/16495) it failed. Do we need it? What do do with it? Why wasn't you there?

My main reasons was:

1. No one there, usually.
2. Drupal Association News I was not interested in. If someone ever wrote anything, it was drowned under these, and slow conversations wasn't possible
3. Login problems - but that was probably my issue with firewall I'm behind. After I finally got logged in, it was hard to find Drupal chatroom again.

So what kind of room would you actually use? My ideas for chat I would frequent more are:

1. Weekly or monthly meetings, to talk about Drupal news, meta issues etc
2. No automatic posts from any organization. I know it may be hard, and I don't know what was the deal between Drupal Association and Stack Exchange team, but honestly, if I will want to know their news, I can see their website, right? And if they are posting it in chat to gain visibility, they are failing miserably now.
3. Rules clearly less stiff. Things loosely associated with Drupal, or just bordering Drupal development, should still be allowed there.
4. Question-specific chats (created due to large amount of comments) should get automatically announced - this would allow anyone with time to chat to participate and help, even if they didn't notice the original post in the first place (due to being in chat, for example).

Answer (score 3):

Chat on other sites is rather active (and in some cases too active and require heavy moderation).  Our isn't.

I suspect the biggest problems is that [Drupal IRC](https://www.drupal.org/irc) is very active with a large number of participants.  It is very easy to get quick help there form smaller things, even the hard (yet small) questions.

Comment: I started to answer this but realized I have meeting soon; will try to expand later.

Comment: Yeah, Drupal's IRC activity is definitely a large reason. I suppose the right answer here could be, "Don't use the chat". Though the SE FAQ has a specific entry about IRC...

Answer (score 2):

I agree, no one was there, usually, which of course meant less motivation to be there.

I don't particularly care if the news is there or not. If a conversation does get going, the problem will solve itself.

I like the idea of weekly/monthly meetings if it helps kickstarting things, but I'm not sure what sort of agenda would make sense.

> Rules clearly less stiff. Things loosely associated with Drupal, or just bordering Drupal development, should still be allowed there.

Absolutely, that seems to be what the chat is for, in my mind.

> Question-specific chats (created due to large amount of comments) should get automatically announced - this would allow anyone with time to chat to participate and help, even if they didn't notice the original post in the first place (due to being in chat, for example).

I like the idea, but can we even do that?